# parallel C code for distance computation

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I've a C code which compute the distance between two sets of nodes (three coordinate each), even though my code has been fast enough yet, I want to boost it up a bit more using parallel computing. I've already found some info about openMP and I'm trying to use it right now, but there's something a bit weird. Without omp the code cpu time is 20s, adding the two pragma lines it takes 160s! How could it happen?

I append my code down here

```
float computedist(float **vG1, float **vG2, int ncft, int ntri2, int jump, float *dist){
    int k = 0, i, j;
    float min = 0;
    float max = 0;
    float avg = 0;
    float *d = malloc(3*sizeof(float));
    float diff;

    #pragma omp parallel
    for(i=0;i<ncft;i+=jump){
        #pragma omp parallel
        for(j=0;j<ntri2;j++){
            d[0] = vG1[i][0] - vG2[j][0];
            d[1] = vG1[i][1] - vG2[j][1];
            d[2] = vG1[i][2] - vG2[j][2];
            diff = sqrt(pow(d[0],2) + pow(d[1],2) + pow(d[2],2));
            if(j==0)
                dist[k] = diff;
            else
                if(diff<dist[k])
                    dist[k] = diff;

        }
        avg += dist[k];
        if(dist[k]>max)
            max = dist[k];
        k++;
    }

    printf("max distance: %f\n",max);
    printf("average distance: %f\n",avg/(int)(ncft/jump));

    free(d);

    return max;
}
```

Thank you so much for any help

Comment: "How could it happen?" - usual cause is inappropriate parallelisation scheme, either through locality of reference or too much synchronisation (or both).

Comment: If you set an environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS to 1, and run your OpenMP program with a single thread, how much time will it take?

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov is it ok putting void omp_set_num_threads(int num_threads) before the parallel loop?

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov I put `omp_set_num_threads(1)` before the parallel loop and it takes 23s using `omp_set_num_threads(2)` it gives 50s!

Comment: The new code looks fine to me. Do you call `computedist` only once, or in a loop (and how many times)? How big are `ntri1` and `ntri2`?

Comment: I call `computedist` the function once. When `ntri1=4000` and `ntri2=90000` it takes more with parallelization, whereas if `ntri1=90000` and `ntri2=90000` it takes a lot of less time to finish the run

Comment: Rolled back to the actual question. If you want to show your final solution, add it, do not delete your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(The answer below refers to the initial code in the question, which since then was improved with applying these suggestions)

---

You need to read more about how to use OpenMP. The specification is available at http://www.openmp.org; and there are links to tutorials and other resources.

I will point out some issues in your code and give recommendations how to fix those.

```
    float *d = malloc(3*sizeof(float));
    float diff;
```

`d` is used as a temporary variable, so should be marked as `private` in `#pragma omp parallel for` (see below) to avoid data races. Meanwhile, instead of dynamic allocation, I would just use 3 separate floats. `diff` also holds a temporary value, so should also be `private`.

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    for(i=0;i<ncft;i+=jump){
        #pragma omp parallel
        for(j=0;j<ntri2;j++){
```

You created a parallel region where each thread executes the whole loop (because the region does not contain any work sharing constructs), and inside it you created a nested region with a new(!) set of threads, also each executing the whole inner loop. It adds lots of overhead and unnecessary computation to your program. What you need is `#pragma omp parallel for`, and only applied to the outer loop.

```
            d[0] = vG1[i][0] - vG2[j][0];
            d[1] = vG1[i][1] - vG2[j][1];
            d[2] = vG1[i][2] - vG2[j][2];
            diff = sqrt(pow(d[0],2) + pow(d[1],2) + pow(d[2],2));
```

Not related to parallelism, but why calling `pow` just to compute squares? A good old multiplication would likely be both simpler to read and faster.

```
            if(j==0)
                dist[k] = diff;
            else
                if(diff<dist[k])
                    dist[k] = diff;
```

Since the action is the same (`dist[k]=diff;`), the code can be simplified by combining two conditions with `||` (logical or).

```
        }
        avg += dist[k];
        if(dist[k]>max)
            max = dist[k];
```

Here you compute aggregate values across the outer loop. In OpenMP, this is done with `reduction` clause of `#pragma omp for`.

```
        k++;
    }
```

Currently, you increment `k` at each iteration, thus creating an unnecessary dependency between iterations that leads to a data race in parallel code. According to your code, `k` is just a convenient "alias" for `i/jump` - so just assign it as such at the beginning of the iteration, and make `private`.

Comment: I've applied all your suggestions but It still does not work properly

Answer (score 2):

You use a lot of synchronization when you add `#pragma omp parallel` on both outer loop and inner loop.

When using `#pragma omp parallel`, there is a [barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29) after the loop, so all threads wait until the last thread finishes.

In your case, you have to wait for all threads both in inner loop and both in outer loop, thus you get a lot of overhead for using syncrhonization.

It is usually best to use `#pragma omp parallel` only on the outer loop [assuming there is enough work there to be done...] to minimize the amount of barriers.

Comment: If I put `#pragma omp parallel` only in the outer loop the program gives me bus error...

Comment: @Nicholas: not sure, but I think if you put `pragma omp parallel for private(i)` only on outer loop you should be fine. This is a different issue so you might want to post a new question with more details about this problem if it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my question using the private stuff and after studing a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you write into an array common to all threads, `dist`. Probably you are having false sharing issues there.
Try to allocate that array with padding.